# Call to undefined function menu_load() in .../public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579

Tags: php, drupal

I really need your help. Actually, my journey begin with the installation Drupal and some modules. After a couple of days I suddenly get an issue "`500 Internal Server Error`".

I asked my hosting provider why this happened, he said "That because of the file .htaccess and you should add to this file php display error". So i did this and I get a new issue :

```
"Fatal error: Call to undefined function menu_load() in ...
/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579."
```

By the way, that's line 579

> else {$return = $function($value);}

**P.S:** I am a beginner in PHP. I like Drupal a lot and want to study Drupal in further and create cool sites, but this problem...

Comment: Related: [Call to undefined function menu_load() in …/public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/82577/1908) at Drupal SE.

Answer (score 0):

need to figure out what function it's trying to call first.
change the line

```
else {$return = $function($value);}
```

to

```
 else {echo $function;exit;$return = $function($value);}
```

Comment: I have changed the line to yours and get a new issue: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ELSE in ...public_html/includes/menu.inc on line 579 What next . What do we do next?

Comment: you sure you didn't accidentally overwrite something else? maybe re-install drupal and try again?

Comment: Maybe, but re-installing in extreme case. Thank you anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here are few tips:

- make sure your Drupal core has all the files in the right place (especially menu module),
- make sure your imported database is in UTF-8 format,
- upgrade your Drupal core to the latest version (`drush fr && drush up drupal`)
- clear all your caches (`drush -y cc all`), including your memcached (`killall memcached`),
- rebuild your registry by using [Registry Rebuild][1],
- if you're using modules which are implementing `drupal_bootstrap()` (such as Secure Site), disable them,
- try disabling your PHP cache engines (such as XCache, Zend optimizer) to see if that's the problem,
- test it on different environment/machine,
- eventually restore your database from the point where it was working before